# Creating Horizontal Scroll and Wrapping Elements

Tags: html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a horizontal scroll that I'm building but the divs end up wrapping to the next line instead of going off screen. In essence I'm trying to create this.

http://codepen.io/calendee/pen/HIuft?editors=100

My CSS looks like

```
.wide-as-needed {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.scroll {
  min-width: 100%;
}

parts * {
  width: 100px;
}

parts {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

My HTML looks like

```
<ion-scroll class="wide-as-needed" direction="x">
    <parts ng-repeat="part in popularParts" part="part"</parts>
</ion-scroll>
```

The parts element sample here

```
<parts ng-repeat="part in popularParts" part="part" class="">
    <div class="text-center">
        <img src="image.png">
        <div class="bold assertive ng-binding">Product 1</div>
        <div class="assertive ng-binding">John Deere</div>
        <div class="bold balanced ng-binding">$88.0</div>
    </div>
</parts>
```

What's wrong and how do I fix this?

Comment: Your code works for me. Try adding a block type to .wide-as-needed (display: block).

Comment: Tried it but no luck. Each `parts` element is wrapped to the next line once it fills up the row.

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to use Ionic? Here is an example with CSS and HTML, not using Ionic.

http://codepen.io/tylerism/pen/zGPQaj

```
.item{  
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background:#333388;
  color:white;
  padding:10px 50px;
  margin-right:10px;
}

.scroll_outer{
  width: auto;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Does that work?

Comment: No, that won't work. Ionic is required. Otherwise I would have already that answer.

Comment: No worries. You gave it a shot.